# Node voltage analysis

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, nodal-analysis

I just wanna ask if \$V_1\$ and \$V_3\$ could be -10V and -20V respectively in this circuit? I just thought of it because I assign the reference node in the middle, so that will be 0V. Because of the reference node, \$V_1\$ and \$V_3\$ will be the same as the voltage sources? Please correct me if I’m wrong.

[image]

Comment: mama b - Hi, You edited the question to add a second question *after* you had already received an answer to the first question. That is not allowed here, as it makes the answer to your first question look incomplete because *you* "moved the goalposts". Therefore I have reverted the question to its original state. || If the original question is solved, please see [this page](/help/someone-answers) & consider "[áccepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234)" your choice of the best answer i.e. click the "tick mark" next to that answer to make it green, to show *this question* has been solved.

Comment: (continued)  You can ask a new question (which must be self-contained and include the schematic with your calculations and best solution attempt etc.) if you still need help on the second calculation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I just wanna ask if V1 and V3 could be -10V and -20V respectively in
> this circuit?*

How can V1 be anything other than 0 volts: -

[image]

You should also recognize the these two resistors are in parallel and therefore the current loop (I2) you drew is meaningless: -

[image]

Comment: Ohhh I think I understand now. Thank you so much for explaining!